# azure function app cant' bind Input request when using Java record

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud

I want to pass Java User object to Azure function app

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    String firstName;
}
```

It can reach the function

```
@FunctionName("hello")
public HttpResponseMessage execute(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
        ExecutionContext context) {
    User user = request.getBody().get;
}
```

But if I change Java class User to Java record object,

```
public record User(String firstName) {}
```

The postman request will be stuck and fail.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to bind Input request with Http Triggered Azure function when using Java record object.

```java
public class HttpTriggerJava {

    @FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        try {
            User user = request.getBody().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Please pass a user object in the request body."));
            String responseMessage = "Hello, " + user.firstName() + "!";

            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .body(responseMessage)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .body("Error: " + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }
    public record User(String firstName) {}
}
```

User class:

```java
public class User{
    String firstName;
    
    public User(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using normal java class like you did. But I was hoping I could use java  record type directly.